# How to access changelog.md file in component in angular?

Tags: angular, http, package, angular7, angular2-routing

I have to display the content in my changelog.md file which is located parallel to package.json file,

```
  I wrote a service for that as follows,

     function getData() {
        return http.get('../changelog.md');
     }
```

But I am getting 404 error not found,can any one please help me to resolve this or else any other best solution.Thanks.

Comment: go to angular.json you will see an attribute asset put the path of changelog in that array so when you build this gets into the distribution folder then your above code should work

Comment: @joyBlanks,I have given the path but got error which says path should with src/

Comment: ah ok. then you need to write a custom shell script to copy this in assets folder after the build, but would be tough for local development

Comment: Any solution for runing in local

Answer (score 2):

Your code is allright, all you need to do is get the non asset file marked as an asset so that it gets copied to your distribution folder with a slight change of path of course

```
function getData() {
  return http.get('/changelog.md');
}
```

If you want to get something as an asset you have to use the glob pattern in the `angular.json` > `architecht` > `build` > `assets` attribute

For example in here favicon.ico and all items in asset folder will be copied to your distribution folder root

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
]
```

For your non asset file to be copied there you have to define it not as a string but as an object which would be like this (All files matching pattern `*.md` will be copied as in README.md and CHANGELOG.md etc to the root folder

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/favicon.png",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "*.md",
    "input": ".",
    "output": "/"
  }
]
```

If you just need the pattern to match CHANGELOG.md you can just specify `"glob": "CHANGELOG.md"`

```
{
  "glob": "changelog.md",
  "input": ".",
  "output": "/"
}
```

So this should be viable for `ng build` and `ng serve` as well.

---

Description of the attributes:

> glob: The pattern to match.
>
> input: The dir to search within
>
> output: The output path (relative to the outDir)

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md